# Is it possible to lock layer order in Layer Browser Panel in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, lock, browser

I want to share my projects with my colleauges. The used projects are really huge because of many implemented layers. In order to prevent struggles (wrong overlapping etc.) within the layer order structure in the browser, I am looking for an option to lock layers (or groups) permanently in the browser window.

Is there any way to do this? I could'nt find any suitable tool or script to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative solution you may use the layer order tab, it won't lock the layers order but can save from unwanted changes in the layer order. From the View/Panels turn on **Layer order panel** and check *Control rendering order* and set the necessary order (it will inherit the order from layer panel).

[image]

Turn off **Layer order panel** and save your project. If you share the project and someone moves a layer in Layer panel up or down, it won't change the display order of layers. On next screenshot you can see I moved the point and the polyline layer under the raster layer, but they are visible (because of the invisible layer order panel settings).

[image]

It can also help you to arrange layers into groups without the restriction of display order.

Comment: great idea. Didn't knew/used this function. Additionally I would mark the layers as required in the project propterties to prevent removing them.

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestions and ideas. I'am not sure if that does the trick. My wish is it to prevent layer shuffling in my group structures during layer activation/ deactivations in my projects. The project consists of a huge bunch of different layer contents (technical aspects, administrative borders, protection areas, ownerships, WMS etc.). We need most of them combined to answer different questions and therefore the existing group structures.